# How to find the closest point on a polyhedron (Wedge)

Tags: c#, algorithm, geometry

How could I get the closest point inside a polyhedron to a point in 3d space using 4 vertices on the wedge (p0,p1,p2,p3)

I have a set of points labelled here:
[3d representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWJdQ.png)

And a random point in 3d space (q)

I've managed to get rectangular prisms to work but I'm not sure about this.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you check Wiki? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_point_method

Comment: I don't see how that answers my question?

Comment: You asked for help, not an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to find the closest point on a polyhedron (Wedge) is to use a convex hull algorithm. This algorithm will take the four vertices of the Wedge (p0,p1,p2,p3) as input and will output the closest point of the Wedge to a given point in 3D space. The convex hull algorithm is available in many libraries, such as CGAL and OpenMesh, and can be implemented in C#. Once you have the closest point, you can then use a distance metric to determine the distance between the two points.